# Unable to get Certificate in HttpServletRequest - httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate") gives null

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I have written SSL enabled spring boot rest service. I want to extract public key of client certificate from http request when service is called.

I am trying with `httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");`
which gives null.

If I try `httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_mgr");`
It gives me SSLSession inside JSSESupport objcet which contains localcertificate but it is private and I cant extract certificate.

Below is my SSL configuration (application.properties):

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned_localhost_sslserver
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl-server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Below is the Client code, I wrote to send certificate to my application:

```
    public void testSeervice(){
    char[] passphrase = "changeit".toCharArray(); //password
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            //KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("D:\\Projects\\certvalidator\\src\\main\\resources\\ssl-server.jks"), passphrase); //path

            //TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509"); //instance
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(keystore);


            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
            context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
            URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443/validate");

            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsCon.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
            httpsCon.setRequestMethod("GET");

            System.out.println("Response Message is " + httpsCon.getResponseMessage());

}
```

Comment: From what I recall `.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` is used to access the *client* certificate, in case of a 2-way SSL communication. The client code you present does not initialize a `KeyManagerFactory`, which tends to prove that you are doing a 1-way SSL (only the server "authenticates" itself to the client, while the server asks no credential to the client). In such a scenario, it is normal behavior that `.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` would return null. Do you want to access the *server* certificate instead ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to access client certificate. I tried adding KeyManageFactory as well, but still no lcuk in getting client cert.  'KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();
        context.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);'

Comment: You first have to configure your server to require a client authentication. Look around something like « needs client auth » and feed the server side ssl configuration with a trust manager. I do not remember enough spring boot by heart to provide an answer but this should get you started.

Comment: I would adive you to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808603/implementing-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot

Comment: Yes, as per your comment, i missed server configuration for client auth. I configured trust store and sent valid trust store through client. Now it's working as expected. Thank you. ☺️

Answer (score 2):

I know it doesn't answer the question but, for everyone arrived here (like me) who either:

- upgraded from tomcat 9 to tomcat 10
- upgraded from Springboot 2.X to Springboot 3.X
- upgraded from Spring 5.X to Spring 6.X
- uses the new Jakarta Servlet APIs in their java web applications

And gets null when retreiving the client certificate using

`getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`

be sure to call getAttribute on the ServletRequest like this instead:

`getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`

The attribute name changed to stay consistent with the new servlet API, see [Jakarta Servlet Specification, Version 5.0](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/blob/5.0.0-RELEASE/spec/src/main/asciidoc/servlet-spec-body.adoc#310-ssl-attributes)