# Spring Boot Security - Certificate - Reject connection if invalid

Tags: spring-boot, security, ssl, certificate

I worked before with OAuth and key-password communication but i did not do anything with certificate's.
However, right now i need to secure machine-machine and machine-user communication with certificate.

Client require that if machine or user will call endpoint in our application, than he need to have the certificate which we used. If not, connection should be rejected. Right now i use self-signed certificate with this properties file:

```
server:
  port: 8093
  ssl:
    enable: true
    key-alias: test
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-store-password: <pass>
    key-store: file:///C:/<path>
```

Is there any configuration setting which could reject that or it should be somehow implemented in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extension ?

To be specified - SSL works right now but when you accept page can be "insecure" as self-signed certificate is used it will let you in. I would like to block this behavior and allow only "authorized" persons with certificate installed on their machines see what we have inside.

Comment: What you want to do is named either `mutual certificate authentication` or `2 way TLS/SSL`. Never done it before, but I believe there should be a lot of resources for spring boot out there.

Comment: @Ryd A : You want client and server to establish trust between themselves using a trusted certificate i.e server needs to present a certificate to authenticate itself to client and client has to present its certificate to server ?

Comment: @Amitkumar Yes, between machines i would like to make mTLS as marek mention - however also i expose several endpoints for the user - i would like to block access to the endpoint if certificate does not exist on clients device.

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808603/implementing-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot . This should help.