# Authenticaton with login and password or with certificate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I have an application with spring boot where the user can authenticate with login and password or by digital certificate.
I try to validate with user and password an it works but  when i tried to validate with certificate, chrome dont show me the windows to select the certificate that i want to use in validation (i have several certificates and the server is secure, etc...)

Any ideas?
I attach the code of my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in case I have put something wrong

```
> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {





    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AdminSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers(PublicUrls.URLS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll();

        }
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        }
    }
        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public static class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


            @Autowired
            CustomAuthenticationProvider2 customAuthProvider2;


            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http.antMatcher("/loginCert*").authorizeRequests()
                        .mvcMatchers(PublicUrls.URLS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                        .and().x509()
                        .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
            }

            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider2);
            }

        }




    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
```

And the config properties are:

> server.ssl.key-store=store/keystore.jks
> server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit server.ssl.key-alias=localhost
> server.ssl.key-password=changeit server.ssl.enabled=true
> server.ssl.client-auth=need server.port=8443

Comment: what does 'the navigator dont show me the window' mean? are you using a browser? client application? postman

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808603/implementing-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot

Comment: i user google chrome and dont show the typical windows in that you select the certificate to use in validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the browser prompt you for client certificate 
You need to set the below Spring property in your application.properties if using embedded tomcat

```
server.ssl.client-auth=need
```

For dedicated tomcat you need to set the below property in your server.xml

```
clientAuth="want"
```

Refer the below tutorial for setting up mutual-auth / 2-way SSL

https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

Comment: When i try this in goolge chrome it response with the following message: Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443. SSL peer cannot verify your certificate.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_ALERT

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: I used the following certificates: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-x509/store

Comment: I suggest you follow the tutorial linked in the answer for any subsequent errors. If your original question is answered, accept the answer and upvote it

Comment: One more question... is any way to pass the cert to userDetailService to do some custom validation?