# Implement both mTLS (two way SSL ) and public endpoints (no SSL check)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a Spring Boot application which has some endpoints:

- `/.wellknown` which does not require any authentication and open to public
- `/callback` which requires mTLS (only cert authentication).

For the above requirement, I cannot find a exact implementation. Most of the implementation

1. find enables mTLS at server level - meaning all APIs are mTLS enabled.
2. with X.509 Certificate check which checks for certificate and user data (In my case there is no user data involved - its only server to server mTLS).

Found below code:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    /*
     * Enables x509 client authentication.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .x509()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                        .disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }
 
    /*
     * Create an in-memory authentication manager. We create 1 user (localhost which
     * is the CN of the client certificate) which has a role of USER.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("localhost").password("none").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Please help on how to implement the same

1. `/callback` - check if the client gives the cert and is available in trust-store
2. `/.well-known/` No mTLS check respond without any check

Comment: One way could be to use only HTTP for `/.well-known/`, so you could enable mTLS in server configuration.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808603/implementing-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend you use the newest approach to configure Spring Security since the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will be deprecated soon.

The way I would implement your scenario is by having 2 `SecurityFilterChain`, one for the `/.well-known` path, and the other one for the rest, using `requestMatchers`, like so:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain wellKnownSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatchers((requests) -> requests
                    .antMatchers("/.well-known")
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .x509(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            )
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

}
```

This way, the `wellKnownSecurity` chain will be applied to the `/.well-known` endpoint, permitting all requests, and the `defaultSecurity` chain will be applied to every other request, requiring `x509`.

Comment: Your solution isn't solving OP's problem. You are using `.x509(Customizer.withDefaults())`, which authenticates an user, but OP has no user at all.

Comment: I've replicated the user code with a solution that will permit access to the `/.well-known` endpoint, as well as having a totally separate configuration to the other endpoints.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio is this *mutual* TLS? this seems like one-way TLS